# Adding column to table based on whether another column = a specific string

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, alter-table

I want to add a column called "Sweep" that contains bools based on whether the "Result" was a sweep or not. So I want the value in the "Sweep" column to be `True` if the "Result" is '4-0' or '0-4' and `False` if it isn't.

This is a part of the table:

[image: A part of the table]

I tried this:

```
ALTER TABLE "NBA_finals_1950-2018"
ADD "Sweep" BOOL;

UPDATE "NBA_finals_1950-2018"
    SET "Sweep" = ("Result" = '4-0' OR "Result" = '0-4');
```

But for some reason, when I run this code...:

```
SELECT *
FROM "NBA_finals_1950-2018"
ORDER BY "Year";
```

...only one of the rows (last row) has the value `True` even though there are other rows where the result is a sweep ('4-0' or '0-4') as shown in the picture below.

[image]

I don't know why this is happening but I guess there is something wrong with the `UPDATE...SET` code. Please help.
Thanks in advance.

NOTE: I am using PostgreSQL 13

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: you should really avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble than they are worth it. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would occur if the strings are not really what they look like -- this is often due to spaces at the beginning or end.  Or perhaps to hyphens being different, or other look-alike characters.

You just need to find the right pattern.  So so with a `select`.  This returns no values:

```
select *
from "NBA_finals_1950-2018"
where "Result" in ('4-0', '0-4');
```

You can try:

```
where "Result" like '%0-4%' or
      "Result" like '%4-0%'
```

But, this should do what you want:

```
where "Result" like '%4%' and
      "Result" like '%0%'
```

because the numbers are all single digits.

You can incorporate this into the `update` statement.

Note:  double quotes are a bad idea.  I would recommend creating tables and columns without escaping the names.

Comment: If you look closely at the image you posted, there are two different-length hyphen characters in the data. The condition `"Result" like '%0%'` should yield what you want.

Comment: Thank you but I used double quotes because I used double quotes in all other rows (I didn't know it was a bad idea before)

Comment: Steve Kass Thank you I didn't notice that.

Comment: `UPDATE "NBA_finals_1950-2018"
SET "Result" = REPLACE("Result", '–', '-')
WHERE "Result" LIKE '%–%';` - It's better to make sure all rows have the same type of hyphen so I used this.

Comment: @SuchirKumaravel . . . I agree.